# Is there an apt command to download a deb file from the repositories to the current directory?

Tags: apt, package-management

I am often interested in the installation triggers (postinst, postrm) or certain parts of packages (like `/usr/share` and `/etc`). Currently, I am running the next command to retrieve the source code:

```
apt-get source [package-name]
```

The downside is, this file is often much bigger than the binary package and does not reflect the installation tree.

Right now, I am downloading the packages through http://packages.ubuntu.com/:

1. [Search for `[package-name]`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql&searchon=names&suite=maverick&section=all)
2. [Select the package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/mysql-server-5.1)
3. [Click on amd64/i386 for download](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/amd64/mysql-server-5.1/download)
4. Download the actual file

This takes too long for me and as someone who really likes the shell, I would like to do something like the next (*imaginary*) command:

```
apt-get get-deb-file [package-name]
```

I could not find something like this in the [apt-get manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/apt-get.8.html). The most close I found was the `--download-only` switch, but this puts the package in `/var/cache/apt/archives` (which requires root permissions) and not in the current directory.

Comment: Differences on machines without saving files: ssh debianmachine1 "dpkg --get-selections" | diff - <(dpkg --get-selections)

Comment: You can use `debget` from the package `debian-goodies`.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use the `download` sub-command of `apt`, `apt-get` or `aptitude`. For example, if **$PKG** is the package you want, any of these will do:

```
apt-get download $PKG
apt download $PKG
aptitude download $PKG
```

This doesn't require root privileges. The same can also be approximated using `apt-get` and `wget`:

```
wget $(apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris -qq $PKG | cut -d"'" -f2)
```

This will, however, fetch all packages required to install the package, so you can attempt to limit it instead:

```
wget $(apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris -qq $PKG | cut -d"'" -f2 | grep "/${PKG}_")
```

You can also put a wget line into a function, to be able to use it as a command apt-download with the package name as a parameter:

```
function apt-download { wget -c $(apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris -qq $1 | cut -d"'" -f2); }
```

Note the modifications: The $PKG is replaced with $1 and the -c parameter enables continuing interrupted downloads.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I'm looking for. Another reason to keep aptitude on my system, the other useful command that is not provided by `apt` is `aptitude changelog $PKG`.

Comment: Update: from Natty (apt version 0.8.11 to be precise), the `aptitude download` feature is available in `apt` as well: `apt-get download $PKG`.

Comment: sweet, works despite my ancient apt v0.8.10

Comment: it seems they did away with the --print-urls option

Comment: The --print-urls option is still there

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this and download for a specific architecture (ie: `amd64`/`i386`/`armhf`/`arm64`)? [I've posted a similarly themed question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770569/get-apt-packages-for-cross-compiling-against-armhf-arm64-platforms), and this gets me about 90% of the way to the finish line. Thank you.

Comment: @Cloud, few years passed, but maybe it'll be useful for someone: I think You can use the syntax `apt download <Package name>:<Architecture>`, for example `apt download ncdu:amd64`.

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt-get -o dir::cache::archives="/path/to/folder/" -d install package
```

Note:

You need to create an folder named partial in destination folder.

Comment: Doesn't sound that bad. The options seems to be described by `man apt.conf`. I would like to avoid the creation of the folder.

Comment: I'm just curious, why would you avoid creating the folder?

Comment: I do not need to store the package forever and avoid creating the folder saves time too.

Comment: Just wanted to note that this solution will also insist on package removal (e.g. if you change version via `/etc/apt/sources.list` to a newer one, with the intent to download later packages) - in such a case, the `wget` method above may be more useful, if you don't want to remove anything...

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu 14.04 (`apt` package version `1.0.1ubuntu2`, I believe), `apt-get` includes the `download` command to download the given package as a `.deb` in the current directory.

For example, suppose we want to download the file manager `Ranger`:

```
$ apt-get download ranger
```

Results in:

```
$ ls . | grep ranger
ranger_1.6.0-1_all.deb
```

Comment: This is perfect. All other solutions I tried don't work if `apt install` can't meet all dependency requirements. I just wanted the .deb file for tinkering!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to download all deb packages from a list, you can do this:

```
cat path/to/text/file.txt | xargs apt-get install --reinstall --print-uris -qq $PKG | cut -d"'" -f2 | xargs wget
```

Just put one package name per line. Like in a requirements.txt file.
For example, with contents like this:

```
apache2-mpm-event
curl
dmidecode
ethtool
libapache2-mod-wsgi
libapache2-mod-python
```

Hope this helps. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install devscripts`

`dget [package-name]`

Comment: How doesn't it provide an answer?  This downloads a deb from the archive to the current directory.  Is that not exactly what the question was?

Comment: A bit more detail may be useful. While this *technically* qualifies as an answer, you may still want to provide more than two commands.

Comment: ::shrug:: Unlike the other answers here, this one has no provisos or caveats.  It's a simple answer to a straightforward question.

Answer (score 0):

`/var/cache/apt/archives` is world readable.  After `apt-get -d`, just extract it from there to your home directory.  Run `dpkg -e /var/cache/apt/archives/foo_version.deb foo` while in your home directory and the control files will be dumped into `foo/`.

Comment: I think the problem with this method is that the download still requires administrative privileges. It seems silly to go to such extremes just to get a file into your home directory.

Comment: Opening the .debs is not the problem, downloading it is. It might be a bug or not, but the packages in /var/cache/apt/archives` are affected by umask too. I've set an umask of 027 and therefore, the packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives` cannot be read by me. As I need just to examine the package contents, I just need to download it once: to `/tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command `debget` which is included in the package `debian-goodies`.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt install debian-goodies
```

Download packages using:

```
debget <package_name>
```

For example:

```
debget debian-goodies
```

Which will download `debian-goodies_0.79_all.deb` in your current directory (do `pwd` to print your current working directory).

Comment: `debian-goodies` comes with lots of useful commands, see also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1170001/777279