# How to read package description or man page without installing?

Tags: package-management, documentation, manpage

How can I get information about a package before installing it, from the terminal?

I mean something like `man` pages, but accessible even before the package is installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

not as extensive as manpages but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
apt-cache show <packagename>
```

you can also search for related packages:

```
apt-cache search <searchtag>
```

Comment: We also have `apt search <packagename>/<searchtag>`

Comment: @PabloBianchi Comparing the two there are some differences. It should be easier to parse the output of `apt-cache search` and it's easier to scroll through the results. Alternatively, `apt search` has highlighted package names in green, the descriptions are tabbed (hanging indent like MLA citations) with a line space in between each result. Apt also shows version and architecture but the green highlighting makes it hard to discern where the list begins if you run more than one list when your username@server is also green and not as easy as piping `awk '{print $1}'` to parse a list of packages.

Comment: Sure, `apt` might be more friendly, but is not oriented to use with pipes (`grep -A/-B 1` options might be handy) or in scripts. As [man states](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/apt.8.html): _All features of `apt` are available in dedicated APT tools like `apt-get` and `apt-cache` as well.  `apt` just changes the default value of some options. So you should prefer using these commands (potentially with some additional options enabled) in your scripts as they keep backward compatibility as much as possible._

Answer (score 13):

### `dman` Retrieves Manual Pages

In practice, [viewing a package's brief description (as mchid suggests)](https://askubuntu.com/a/605341/22949) is usually what you'll want to see, to decide if you want the package. However, if you like you can view a manpage provided by a package that has not yet been installed, using the [`dman`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/dman.1.html) utility.

`dman` is [provided](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=dman&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) by the [bikeshed](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bikeshed) [image: Install bikeshed] package. You can install that in the Software Center, or with `sudo apt-get install bikeshed`.

Then use `dman` like `man`.

`dman` is a script that retrieves manual pages over the Internet and displays them, so you have to be connected to the Internet to use it successfully. (But you probably are, because in your specific scenario you're about to install a package.) It also often runs slowly, so be prepared to wait several seconds.

### If `dman`'s database doesn't have your release, you can specify another.

[Due to a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bikeshed/+bug/1243092) `dman` doesn't work right on some releases of Ubuntu. For now you can get around the problem by viewing another release's version of the manpage you want (this workaround was suggested by [Marius Gedminas](https://launchpad.net/%7Emgedmin) in [a comment on the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bikeshed/+bug/1243092/comments/3)). You use [the adjective part of the codename](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), in all lower case (e.g., `precise` from 12.04 Precise Pangolin, `trusty` from 14.04 Trusty Thar). For example:

```bsh
ek@Io:~$ dman sl       # doesn't work on Vivid, produces no output
ek@Io:~$ dman --release trusty sl

SL(6)                            Games Manual                            SL(6)

NAME
       sl  -  display animations aimed to correct users who accidentally enter
       sl instead of ls.

SYNOPSIS
       sl [ -alFe ]

DESCRIPTION
       sl Displays animations....
```

### Alternative: Browse Manual Pages with a (Text-Based) Web Browser

Of course, you can also simply [browse the manpages on the web](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/). If you want to do this from the command-line, you can [use a text-based web browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29540/browsing-the-internet-from-the-command-line).

If you like, you could even define [a function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions) in [`.bashrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) so you have a command that opens up a text-based web browser and searches for the term passed as its argument:

```bsh
wman() { links2 "http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=$1"; }
```

For that particular function definition to work, the [links2](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/links2) [image: Install links2] package must be installed. It will cause the `wman` function to be defined automatically in each newly created interactive shell, but not in shells that were started before `.bashrc` was edited (you could simply run the function definition in those shells, though).

Then I can search for manual pages, and select between pages in different sections of the manual, for whichever Ubuntu release's version of the manual I like:

```bsh
ek@Io:~$ wman chmod

                                            Ubuntu Manpage: Searching (p1 of 2) 
                                 Ubuntu manuals                                 
                                                                                
   _____________________ go                                                     
                                                                                
   +------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
   |  lucid      precise    trusty     utopic     Section Description       |   
   |  10.04 LTS  12.04 LTS  14.04 LTS  14.10                                |   
   |  chmod(1),  chmod(1),  chmod(1),  chmod(1),  (1) - Executable          |   
   |  chmod(1)   chmod(1)   chmod(1)   chmod(1)   programs or shell         |   
   |                                              commands                  |   
   |  chmod(2),  chmod(2),  chmod(2),  chmod(2),  (2) - System calls        |   
   |  chmod(2)   chmod(2)   chmod(2)   chmod(2)   (functions provided by    |   
   |                                              the kernel)               |   
   |                                              (3) - Library calls       |   
   |  chmod(3)   chmod(3)   chmod(3)   chmod(3)   (functions within         |   
   |                                              program libraries)        |   
   |      .          .          .          .      (4) - Special files       |   
   |                                              (usually found in /dev)   |   
   |                                              (5) - File formats and    |   
   |      .          .          .          .      conventions eg            |   
   |                                              /etc/passwd               |   
   |      .          .          .          .      (6) - Games               |   
   |                                              (7) - Miscellaneous       |   
   |      .          .          .          .      (including macro          |   
   |                                              packages and              |   
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/
```

Comment: +1 `dman` is an extremely useful idea.

Comment: I recommend `debman`.

Comment: Instead of installing `bikeshed`, you can install `debian-goodies` which will give you both `dman` and `debman`

Comment: For example to view manpage for `debman` which is part of the `debian-goodies` package you can use `debman -p debian-goodies debman`. If you have a `.deb` package on your computer you can use `-f` option to view manpages of it without installing that package: `debman -f debian-goodies_0.79_all.deb debman`

Comment: @Shayan I believe this is very useful and deserves its own answer. Would you be willing to post one?

Comment: @EliahKagan ok I will try :D

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing `debian-goodies` package which will give you access to the `dman`, `debman`, `debmany`, and `debget` commands, and many more. Install it with:

```
sudo apt install debian-goodies
```

`dman` has already been covered by [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/a/605348/777279).

Now you know `dman` is both included in `bikeshed` and `debian-goodies`.

---

You can use debman to read man pages from uninstalled (not installed) packages.

In these examples I want to read the man page of `dman` from package `debian-goodies`:

```
debman -p debian-goodies dman
```

Or if you're looking to read man pages for a specific version, use:

```
debman -p debian-goodies=0.79 dman
```

You can also read local `.deb` files' manpage using the `-f` option:

```
debman -f debian-goodies_0.79_all.deb dman
```

Just for clarity, here's another example, I want to read the man page of `apt-get` tool which belongs to the `apt` package:

```
debman -p apt apt-get
```

So you need to know the command which you want to read it's man page belongs to which package.

---

You can download packages with `debget` and read them manually with your favorite app:

```
debget debian-goodies
```

man pages and other documentation are included in `.deb` packages, they can be found in:

```
debian-goodies_0.79_all.deb\data.tar\usr\share\man
debian-goodies_0.79_all.deb\data.tar\usr\share\doc
```

---

Or you can use `debmany` to view all documentation using terminal:

```
debmany ./debian-goodies_0.79_all.deb
```

You can also use it for installed packages:

```
debmany debian-goodies
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm on my android phone and sometimes even when I'm on Ubuntu I will use internet to view man pages. Another benefit of internet browser is ability to easily search with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. In your browser search bar you can type `man ls` and this is the first hit:

[image: man ls]

Answer (score -1):

In my Opinion you can't read the documentation without installing the package. when you install any specific package you may have noticed some additional files also gets installed one of which is named as 'man-db' or something similar.

This 'man-db' actually contains the manual documentation about the package.

but you can see some basic details of the package by

```
apt-cache show <packagename>
```

Comment: The first part about `man-db` becomes relevant only after package installation (which OP doesn't want).