# How to install a package offline

Tags: software-installation, offline, pencil

I want to install pencil 0.4.4b, on an ubuntu machine that is not connected to the internet.

Is there a way I can copy all the source files or preferably a .deb file and any dependencies to a usb and then install from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the .deb files using a connected device
2. Transfer them to the non-connected machine
3. Install them using `sudo dpkg -i package_1.deb package_2.deb`

Comment: how to find the list of .deb files for a particular software and how to find them on online machine?

Comment: One idea is to use "apt-cache search keyword", with the keyword being the software name. And for the other question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/30482/is-there-an-apt-command-to-download-a-deb-file-from-the-repositories-to-the-curr