# Download a .deb file without installing on a non debian device without using apt

Tags: 20.04, deb, debian, curl, debian-installer

Is it possible to simply download a deb file using curl or get it without having to dig for the URLs from the ppa file or use apt? Mainly to simple download the file from other non debian Linux distros or even Macs and windows?

Context...I am trying to package the. nginx deb file for an application in cloudfoundry using the apt-buildpack.   https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack#cloud-foundry-experimental-apt-buildpack which can take a local deb file and install them. (Probably deb's of dependencies as well maybe).

The environment will not have access to external repo so everything needs to be packaged and pushed including the deb file. Also, I don't want to use the nginx buildpack.

I saw an approach of using [wget (by getting the URL from apt)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30482/is-there-an-apt-command-to-download-a-deb-file-from-the-repositories-to-the-curr). But is there any other way to get the URL without apt?

Comment: How do you want do download a file if you don't know from where? And how to do that on non-Ubuntu OS is definitely out of scope here.

Comment: I'm often using `wget` to download them, but I don't see the point to your question... grabbing the *deb* is the easy part

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be asking a couple different things. A deb file, is a package, not unlike a zip file, except the .deb file has a set of rules, and contents that when executed install a source code, or binary to your Debian based Linux distribution.

While you can of course download, and not install a debfile, depending on the repository, a matching deb file may or may not be available.

Which deb files / source code exactly?
From what source?

> Mainly to simple download the file from other non debian Linux distros
> or even Macs and windows?

This part, might be a point of confussion. A deb file is not source code, it is an installer package for debian systems.

It is / or may be possible to compile source code on various distributions but this is beyond the scope of a deb file.

please update your question with what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Context...I am trying to package the. nginx deb file for an application in cloudfoundry using the apt-buildpack.   https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack#cloud-foundry-experimental-apt-buildpack which can take a local deb file and install them.
 The environment will not have access to external repo so everything needs to be packaged and pushed including the deb file. Also, I don't want to use the nginx buildpack.